# Kotlin: Difference in definition of Collection

Tags: dictionary, collections, kotlin

What is differences in Kotlin between this:

```
val customerProducts = mutableMapOf<Customer, Set<Product>>()
```

and this:

```
val customerProducts: MutableMap<Customer, Set<Product>> = mutableMapOf()
```

Comment: Second statement won't compile.

Answer (score 3):

Your second example won't compile, but I'll assume you meant this:

```
val customerProducts: MutableMap<Customer, Set<Product>> = mutableMapOf()
```

To answer the question, there is no difference. You have to provide the type parameters of the `Map` you're creating somewhere, and then it will be inferred in the other location. It's up to you which one you want to use.

- If you provide this information on the left side of the assignment, with an explicit variable type, it will be inferred by the `mutableMapOf` function.
- If you provide it on the right side to the `mutableMapOf` function, then the type of the variable will be inferred.